# Using CASL in nuxt 3 as plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs3, nuxt3, casl

I am trying to create an app using nuxt 3 and I need to implement CASL as a plugin using `defineNuxtPlugin` which can fetch the user permissions from database and create the abilities from the data fetched from db

Tried searching the web for a solution but all I get is old codes for nuxt 2 which are not using defineNuxtPlugin

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.